# fail in installing Google Chrome in 12.04 both 32 & 64 bit

Tags: google-chrome

I have copied my terminal information can you help me with this problem?

```
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo dkg --install /Path/to/chrome.web 
[sudo] password for mig: 
sudo: dkg: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo aåt-get install -f
sudo: aåt-get: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Indlæser pakkelisterne... Færdig
Opbygger afhængighedstræ        
Læser tilstandsoplysninger... Færdig
E: Pakken google-chrome-stable:i386 skal geninstalleres, men jeg kan ikke finde noget arkiv med den.
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
dpkg: fejl under behandling af /Path/to/chrome.deb (--install):
 kan ikke tilgå arkivet: No such file or directory
Der opstod fejl under behandlingen:
 /Path/to/chrome.deb
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install libxss1 libnspr4-0d libcurl3
Indlæser pakkelisterne... Færdig
Opbygger afhængighedstræ        
Læser tilstandsoplysninger... Færdig
E: Pakken google-chrome-stable:i386 skal geninstalleres, men jeg kan ikke finde noget arkiv med den.
mig@ubuntu:~$ install google chrome
install: cannot stat `google': No such file or directory
mig@ubuntu:~$ dpkg --install /to/chrome.deb
dpkg: error: den ønskede handling kræver superbrugerrettigheder
mig@ubuntu:~$ gigimus
gigimus: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ mark all
The program 'mark' can be found in the following packages:
 * mailutils-mh
 * nmh
Try: sudo apt-get install 
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install
Indlæser pakkelisterne... Færdig
Opbygger afhængighedstræ        
Læser tilstandsoplysninger... Færdig
E: Pakken google-chrome-stable:i386 skal geninstalleres, men jeg kan ikke finde noget arkiv med den.
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo get-apt autoclean^C
mig@ubuntu:~$ ^C
mig@ubuntu:~$ ^C
```

Comment: what you are trying?Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: If you have downloaded a Chrome .deb file, you were close with your first command: try `sudo dpkg -i /Path/to/chrome.deb`

Comment: don't directly apply the above command where `/Path/to/chrome.deb` means the system path where chrome.deb file is actually stored.You can also get it by rightclicking on the chrome.deb file and then selecting the properties option.

Comment: I downloadede it from google chrome homepage.

Comment: And please confirm your commands before pressing enter. `sudo dkg --install /Path/to/chrome.web` should be `sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.web`, `sudo aåt-get install -f` should be `sudo apt-get install -f`. Check [this tutorial on how to use the terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal).

Comment: Look also at this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/79280/how-to-install-chrome-browser-properly-via-command-line

Comment: me @ ubuntu: ~ $ sudo apt-get install chrome browser
[sudo] password for me:
Reading package lists ... Ready
builds dependency
Reading state information ... Ready
E: The package google-chrome-stable: i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can not find an archive for it.
me @ ubuntu: ~ $ Chromium browser
Chromium: command not found
me @ ubuntu: ~ $ ^ C
me @ ubuntu: ~ $
me @ ubuntu: ~ $ google-chrome-stable
google-chrome-stable: command not found
me @ ubuntu: ~ $ google-chrome-stable - The web browser from Google
google-chrome-stable: command not found

Comment: You are messing things very badly.Simply just double click, the file will open in software center and then click install.

Answer (score 1):

The correct app is `dpkg`, not `dkg`.Also correct extention is `.deb` and not `.web`.

So your command must be `sudo dpkg --install /Absolute/Path/to/chrome.deb`

> Absolute path means you start from `/home/{user}/` and not from you home directory.

For example, consider you have stored your file in `abc/def/chrome.deb`.
Then your command will be `sudo dpkg --install $HOME/abc/def/chrome.deb` or `sudo dpkg --install /usr/<whatever your user name may be, mine is aditya, so I'll put aditya here.You put your's>/abc/def/chrome.deb`

An easier way,right click the .deb package and select open with Ubuntu software center.Then select install.

An third way, install `gdebi` by using this command.`sudo apt-get install gdebi`.Then right click on your file,select open with gdebi and click install.

Comment: MIG @ ubuntu: ~ $ sudo dpkg - install / Absolut / sti / til / chrome.deb
[sudo] password til MIG:
dpkg: error under consideration AF / Absolut / sti / til / chrome.deb (- install):
  cannot find Arkive: no such  file eller map, error under processing:
  / Absolut / sti / til / chrome.deb
MIG @ ubuntu: ~ $

Comment: my softwareceter does not work and synaptic center also out

Comment: in the upper right side of the screen there is a message as follows
an error occurred. please run Package Manager from the right click menu or apt-get in terninalen to see what is wrong. error message was unknown error type exceptions error (E the package google-chrome-stable to be reinstalled but I can not find the file to it. this usually means
that the installed packages do not have all they rely on installed

Comment: g @ ubuntu : ~ $ sudo run apt-get update
No command 'run' found , did you mean :me @ ubuntu : ~ $ sudo Run apt-get update
Run: command not found
me @ ubuntu : ~ $ sudo apt- get install ubuntu- tweak
Reading package lists ... Ready
builds dependency
Reading state information ... Ready
E : The package google- chrome -stable : i386 needs to be reinstalled , but I can not fix it

Comment: I should have made it simpler.I'll do it now.

Comment: I cannot get into ubuntu tweak lokk at the

Comment: mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo-apt-repository: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo-apt-repository: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
sudo-apt-repository: command not found
mig@ubuntu:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tualatrix/ppa
[sudo] password for mig: 
You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
 The official Ubuntu Tweak stable repository
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix/+archive/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

regards jorgen denmark 74 year

Answer (score 0):

Just [install Ubuntu Tweak](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak) and under the apps tab, you will find a link to install Google Chrome directly.

---

**EDIT**

Check images below:

[image]

[image]

Though now in your case, you will have to check the checkbox and then click install.
Hope it works out.

Comment: i have search in dash hme with no result.  have also problem with software center and synaptic- package bacause i cannot reinstall google crome and cannot get rid of it.

Comment: in the upper right side of the screen there is a message as follows
an error occurred. please run Package Manager from the right click menu or apt-get in terninalen to see what is wrong. error message was unknown error type exceptions error (E the package google-chrome-stable to be reinstalled but I can not find the file to it. this usually means
that the installed packages do not have all they rely on installed

Comment: maybee I should reinstall 12,04 and how can I do that??

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and include any errors you will get here.

Comment: Fetched 3,816 kB in 12s (308 kB / s)
Reading package lists ... Ready
Reading package lists ... Ready
builds dependency
Reading state information ... Ready
E: The package google-chrome-stable: i386 needs to be reinstalled, but I can not find an archive for it.

  it went fine until this account came and then I went no further
I am 75 years and I am very interested for both Linux and Windows.

Comment: @user245738 Have a look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/145549/having-problems-with-update-manager It has a solution for the error you're getting. Thank you for using Ubuntu and in case of anything, the community is here for you. We got your back pal.

Comment: Another question in [Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/): http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664969

Comment: I tried your good advice but didnot succed

Comment: your good advice was not enough to help i tried them all

Comment: me @ ubuntu: ~ $ sudo apt-get purge google-chrome-stable
[sudo] password for me:
Reading package lists ... Done
builds dependency
Reading state information ... Done
N: Ignoring file 'google-chrome' in directory '/ etc / apt / sources.list.d /' as it does not have the a file extension
E: The package google-chrome-stable: i386 skal be reinstalled, but I can not find an archive for it.
me @ ubuntu: ~ $ sudo dpkg - remove - force-remove-reinstreq google-chrome-stable
dpkg: warning: there's no installed package matching google-chrome-stable
me @ ubuntu: ~ $

Comment: i will tell you what i did .I had ubuntu install via pendrive on