# Google Chrome install

Tags: installation

Hi I am new to Ubuntu Linux, I have installed on my dell latitude d600 every thing's smooth and fast, I have bean trying to install Google chrome, which I would like to use on Ubuntu, but unfortunately, it shell will not let me install it on my laptop.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!, what did you try to get chrome installed? And what is the error you get when trying to install via shell?

Comment: As a an alternative you can try to install chromium, like so: `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`

Comment: You can also visit Google Chrome website, download the deb file, install it easily using the Package Installer.

Comment: See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/418569/163331) on how to install it using [ubuntu tweak](http://askubuntu.com/questions/75454/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-tweak)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following.

Use this code for *32-bit* system:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
```

For *64-bit* system use:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

This installs a needed library for Google Chrome, then downloads the latest version of Chrome to  the current working directory and installs it.

Run `google-chrome`to start the browser.

---

You can also download it here [`Download Google Chrome`](http://www.google.com/chrome?platform=linux&hl=en).

Comment: When you open the terminal it is automatically in your home folder, not in the `/tmp` folder. One needs to do `cd /tmp` before using `wget`. And just search for `chrome` in the dash. `google-chrome` implies it needs to be started via terminal. Which is only handy when trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

### Non terminal Method

If you are not a much of a terminal user you can go ahead to this [link](https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/#eula) and download directly.

### Using terminal

**Step 1:** Getting .deb installer

For Google Chrome 32-bit version

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
```

For Google Chrome 64-bit version

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

**Step 2:** Installing Google Chrome

Use this command to install Google Chrome or you can also do it by double clicking the downloaded file.

*Use the code below if you prefer doing it using terminal command*

```
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*
```

google-chrome* *refers to the full  name of the file you installed*

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now you have successfully installed Google Chrome. Launch it by searching Chrome in Unity Dash.

Enjoy!

You can also refer to my blogpost [here](http://diynp.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu.html)

Comment: If you are down voting let me know what actually is the problem in the answer.